# How c++ manages the memory of a container in class?

Tags: c++, vector

In c++, when all the memory allocated to a container (say vector) is used up (and we are trying to add one more element), the memory will be reallocated. However, I was wondering that how class in c++ manages the memory for containers.

For example, I run the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Test{
public:
    int i = 0;
    std::vector<int> v;
};

int main(){
    Test t;
    std::cout << "Address of t: " << &t << ", capacity of vector: " << t.v.capacity() << ", size of vector: " << t.v.size() << ", address of vector: " << &(t.v) << std::endl;

    t.v.push_back(1);
    std::cout << "Address of t: " << &t << ", capacity of vector: " << t.v.capacity() << ", size of vector: " << t.v.size() << ", address of vector: " << &(t.v) << std::endl;

    t.v.push_back(2);
    std::cout << "Address of t: " << &t << ", capacity of vector: " << t.v.capacity() << ", size of vector: " << t.v.size() << ", address of vector: " << &(t.v) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

Address of t: 0x61fee8, capacity of vector: 0, size of vector: 0, address of vector: 0x61feec

Address of t: 0x61fee8, capacity of vector: 1, size of vector: 1, address of vector: 0x61feec

Address of t: 0x61fee8, capacity of vector: 2, size of vector: 2, address of vector: 0x61feec

The address of the vector is not changed. Does it mean the c++ uses a pointer to represent each data member (so address 0x61feec actually points to the address of the vector)?

Comment: Try printing out the address of the first element of the vector (`&t.v[0]`, when the vector isn't empty). That might help you understand what's going on

Comment: The address of the vector is not changed because the address of an object never changes. This is one of the fundamental principles of C++. Typically a vector holds a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array of element, it is this array which is reallocated from time to time.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector describes how a vector works.

Answer (score 1):

> The address of the vector is not changed.

Correct, because the `vector` itself is not moving around in memory.

> Does it mean the c++ uses a pointer to represent each data member (so address 0x61feec actually points to the address of the vector)?

Everything in memory has an address.

The `std::vector` class internally contains a data member that is a pointer to an array of elements. The [`vector::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) method reports the number of valid elements in the array, while the [`vector::capacity()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) method reports the maximum number of elements the array is allocated to hold.  The `vector` (re-)allocates that array dynamically as needed, ie whenever the `size()` is equal to the `capacity()` when adding new elements.

Nothing in your example code is printing the address of that array itself.  The [`vector::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) method returns a pointer to that array.  Add that pointer to your logging, and you will see it change value as the `capacity()` changes over time, eg:

```cpp
void log(const Test &t)
{
    std::cout << "Address of t: " << &t
              << ", capacity of vector: " << t.v.capacity()
              << ", size of vector: " << t.v.size()
              << ", address of vector: " << &(t.v)
              << ", address of vector data: " << t.v.data()
              << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    Test t;
    log(t);

    for(int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        t.v.push_back(i);
        log(t);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory is embedded into the containing class. Let's look at an easy example:

```
struct myvector {
   size_t size;
   void* data;
}

class Test {
   myvector v;
}
```

In this case, new objects of class `Test` will be allocated with `sizeof(size_t)+sizeof(void*)` bytes.

Now when it comes to resizing the vector, all that is done, is a realloc() on the memory pointed to by `data`.

Of course, the `std::vector` implementation is far more complicaten than that, but I think you get the idea.